# Azure functions cannot handle binary Azure Servicebus messages

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-function-app

Or how do I get Azure Functions to handle binary Azure Servicebus messages.
Here is my Azure Functions method:

```
public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("firstqueue", Connection = "AzureServicebusConnection")] Message myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    var deSerializedMessage = BinarySerializer.Deserialize(myQueueItem.Body);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{myQueueItem} Body:{deSerializedMessage.GetType().FullName}");
}
```

If I serialize my objects with JSON and then convert them to a byte array then Azure Functions can handle them

```
string messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody);
```

but if I use a binary serializer to create my byte array directly Azure functions cannot handle it

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, command);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

I get the following error message.

> Exception while executing function: CommandReceiver. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: The Message with ContentType 'null' failed to deserialize to a string with the message: 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The input source is not correctly formatted.'. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The input source is not correctly formatted. System.Private.DataContractSerialization: The input source is not correctly formatted.

This binary serializer works if I use a Console application to read the Queue, but I want to use Serverless.

It seems like I need to set the correct content type on the message when it is sent, so it is not trying to convert it to a string but I can not find what that setting might be. Or if this is even the correct solution.

Comment: Azure Functions assumes the default content type is json afair.

Comment: So how do you change it?